# Como mover datos de un array a otro creado con el tamaño justo para esos datos

Tags: c++

Crear un array de tipo int llamado array_de_enteros inicializado a
{2,32,7,54,36,37,42,425, 43,23,125,63,26}. Escribir un programa que
copie los elementos divisibles entre 3 de array_de_enteros a otro array
de enteros llamado array_divisibles_por_tres que se creará con el
tamaño necesario.

Me dice que la variable count no es constante por lo que no puedo definir el tamaño del array. No se me ocurre como hacerlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int array_de_enteros[] = { 2,32,7,54,36,37,42,425,43,23,125,63,26 };

int tam = sizeof(array_de_enteros) / sizeof(int);

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        if (array_de_enteros[i] % 3 == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int array_divisibles_entre_tres[count]; 
    int count2=0;
    for (int id = 0; id < tam; id++)
    {
        if (array_de_enteros[id] % 3 == 0)
            array_divisibles_entre_tres[count2] = array_de_enteros[id];
        count2++;
    }
    for (int idc = 0; idc < count; idc++)
        printf("%d ", array_divisibles_entre_tres);
}
```

Comment: Ese error te sale porque para alocar un arreglo en el stack necesita saberse el tamaño en tiempo de compilación. Si el arreglo va a ser siempre ese, pues simplemente quema la cantidad de números divisibles por tres. Aunque me imagino que eso no es lo que buscas. Entonces podrías alocar el arreglo en el heap usando new.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene algunos otros errores, sin embargo, en el apartado que mencionas, tal como dice JhonRayo99, es necesario utilizar memoria dinámica en lugar de memoria estática, que es el método que estás utilizando. Como regla de oro, recuerda que cada vez que no sabes bien qué tan grande va a ser tu arreglo, es preferible utilizar la memoria dinámica. Para crear el mismo arreglo en memoria dinámica, en lugar de que tengas esto:

`int array_divisibles_entre_tres[count];`

Tiene que ser así

`int *array_divisibles_entre_tres = new int[count];`

En lenguaje C, cada vez que creas un arreglo, es en realidad un puntero con dirección que apunta al primer elemento. En el caso de la memoria dinámica es más evidente. Recuerda que sólo puedes utilizar el operando new con punteros.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), pero antes tienes que convertir tu arreglo simple en un vector (puedes ver darle click [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777603/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-array-to-vector) para más informacion)

```cpp
#include <vector>
...

int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> a(std::begin(array), std::end(array));

// Imprimiendo el tamaño
printf("%d\n", a.size()); // 4

// Moviendo los vectores
std::vector<int> b = std::move(a);

printf("%d\n", a.size()); // 0
printf("%d\n", b.size()); // 4
```

Una cosa que debes tener en cuenta es que si quieres obtener el puntero del vector, debes usar &my_vector[0] (esto se llama **decadencia de arreglos**)